# Radeon R9 270X blank screen on any OS only after installing drivers?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, boot, graphics-card, amd-radeon

I had to go back to my old computer and after about 6 months of it not being powered on, I reinstalled Windows 7.

After I got it up and running, I installed the video drivers. After restarting I'd get past the BIOS screen and than nothing happens. It will just remain a black screen.

My monitor doesn't turn off so it is outputting something. I tried installing Ubuntu, but after it installs it reboots and gets to the GRUB menu, and than freezes on the Ubuntu boot screen.

I managed to get the video to work using the integrated GPU  and it booted up. I did something that I forgot that made Ubuntu get past the boot screen, but than just show a white screen. I got Ubuntu to work by editing the grub boot options and adding radeon.modeset=0.

I switched back to Windows 7 due to wanting to game and using the integrated GPU caused video glitches in video games. But can't install any video drivers

Answer (score -1):

MSI 270x...same issue. I figured out that gpu hates any driver...I have to go into safe mode and uninstall drivers from device management for it to work. Still searching for a suitable driver...going back to ver 13 and seeing how I get on

Comment: Welcome to Super User. The site's Q&A format reserves answers for solutions to the question.  This post is really a comment rather than an answer. You can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).  Non-answers tend to attract downvotes and are subject to deletion.